# Font secure loading with @font-face

Tags: css, security, font-face

I want to use a custom font on a website and want to secure it. I know there is like Cufon etc, but I want to do it with @font-face, because Cufon changes the text with  and @font-face only apply the font to the text. So I found fontdeck.com and they use @font-face with secure font loading.

I have to include a CSS file with the following code:

`@font-face {
    font-family: 'Proxima Nova Thin';
    src: url('http://f.fontdeck.com/f/1/c0NxWjZ3YjEABIN8EILvJ0RNEaQrLMTNf/ckiJrqjmmED2eZzkurKBHRmOyi18vUlxuV1sPQGGKg/w.eot');
    src: url('http://f.fontdeck.com/f/1/c0NxWjZ3YjEABIN8EILvJ0RNEaQrLMTNf/ckiJrqjmmED2eZzkurKBHRmOyi18vUlxuV1sPQGGKg/w.eot?') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('http://f.fontdeck.com/f/1/c0NxWjZ3YjEABIN8EILvJ0RNEaQrLMTNf/ckiJrqjmmED2eZzkurKBHRmOyi18vUlxuV1sPQGGKg/w.woff') format('woff'),
    url('http://f.fontdeck.com/f/1/c0NxWjZ3YjEABIN8EILvJ0RNEaQrLMTNf/ckiJrqjmmED2eZzkurKBHRmOyi18vUlxuV1sPQGGKg/w.ttf') format('opentype');
    font-weight: 100;
    font-style: normal;
}`

But if I go to with the browser to the URL's for EOT, WOFF and TTF files, I will see "Forbidden".

Can somebody explain me how this works?

Comment: Are the fonts actually being applied to your text?

Comment: If i'm correct, the font with @font-face is applied to text and not converted like Cufon.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be finding measures to prevent hotlinking: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_linking#Prevention

> Some servers are programmed to use the HTTP referrer to detect hot-linking and return a condemnatory message, commonly in the same format, in place of the expected image or media clip. Most servers can be configured to partially protect hosted media from inline linking, usually by not serving the media or by serving a different file.

There can be both ethical and legal implications to hotlinking.
I strongly suggest you read about it.

Comment: Thanks ANeves. I think this will help a lot. Because the font is for sale on the website, but I want to use the font to show the possibilities with the font on the website. I'm gonna try to see what i can do to protect the font by disable hotlinking with mod_rewrite.

Comment: @Hopje123 Ah, sorry, I meant that the font file on **their** server is protected. Meaning you can probably only use it from their pages, or maybe the file address changes dinamically, or something along those lines... if you want to showcase using the new font, perhaps you can demonstrate with a different and free one; and then, after getting the ok, buy the real one?

Comment: The code i get from fontdeck is a link to their CSS files with links to their fonts. I want to do the same for my websites, with my own font. So in that case I think you solution with the hotlinking is good. Because I can stop hotlinking with htaccess and only use my own font on my own website. So nobody can go to www.mywebsite.com/font.tff and download it.

Comment: I apologise, but I think maybe I still understand... Mondays, you know! But I'm glad I was helpful.

Comment: No problem, if I know i'm right with you hot linking tip, I show it.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot secure a font using @font-face.  For the font to be applied to the text on the client it has to be sent to the client.

Many fonts have specific license restrictions that spell out whether or not it is ok to use @font-face.  It is best to check your licenses with your legal department.

Comment: When I check the code and inspect the website when I'm using fontdeck.com script. It will show no font on my computer and if I inspect the site it show only http://f.fontdeck.com/f/1/SWlBWFVzS0cAA/M9N/iPRxV4qbfW9IY+x9cJ6DSnBXV3c4uBmH3AvPpF.ttf and that is forbidden to download.

Comment: Give me a link to the page the font is rendered on and I can tell you how to get the font.  There are a few workarounds to make it harder to get the font but you can't make it impossible.

Comment: This is the CCS link:
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://f.fontdeck.com/s/css/tw8rERty3+tZwbQpfxuhJVo9m7Q/ontwikkel5.pingonline.nl/15392.css" type="text/css" />
This is the only I have to include. The CSS files links to 4 @font-face fonts. I didn't find a way to download the fonts, so if you can, I know this isn't a good idea to use.